# detect emulation in intel XDK

Tags: intel-xdk

Is there a way using the Intel XDK library to determine if my app is running in the IDE's emulator vs. on an actual mobile device? I'd like to put in some logging and debugging code that is conditional on this information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect if you are testing/emulating your application in the XDK with the Intel XDK Javascript API. There is a property called *isxdk* which is a boolean value indicating if you are currently running in Intel XDK.

For example,

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
        *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
        input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        body { background-color:white; color:black }
    </style>
    <script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Intel native bridge is available */
        var onDeviceReady=function(){
        //hide splash screen
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        };
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
    </script>
    <script>
        if (intel.xdk.isxdk==true){
            // Application is running in XDK
            alert("Running in Intel XDK Emulator");    
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to Intel XDK</h1>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</body>
</html>
```

For more information on the isxdk property, visit https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493507.

Comment: This is not available anymore in newer XDK versions (3491). Any ideas?

Comment: Found a solution: use the device plugin and in your javascript code `device.isVirtual`

Answer (score 0):

Most methods of detection for this are more trouble than necessary.  Have you tried logging to the javascript console?  A line such as: console.log("X is" + x); to log a variable, or console.log(e); where e is an event can provide significant information when debugging (having the debug screen open in the emulator, or pulling up the javascript console when running in a browser) but remains invisible when on a mobile device.

Comment: Another reason I want to detect if it's emulation is because in the emulator I want it to connect to a server on localhost.